# spring reactive: check if user exists or not

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring reactive and need to check weather user with particular 
data exists or not and currently I am not able to solve that problem.

Considering the scenerio

In my document I need to check if username or email already exists or not

In RDBS I can do it as
`select count(id)>0 where username='abc' or email='abc@idx.com'`

while using spring reactive which returns either mono or flux the simple most query becomes 
`{$or:[{"username":"abc"},{"email":"abc@idx.com"}]}` which will return `flux` but I need boolean to verify from db

On solution is that I can get `Flux<User>` and the iterate it using form loop but then using ' result.block()' whick will block some other threads and therefore not a clean solution.

Is there any clean solution or any Idea how to solve this.

Thanks

**Edit** One possible solution can be creating unique indexing in monogdb, that I am using right now. But if there is any other solution please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Data MongoDB, you can use something like below:

```
public interface ReactiveUserRepository extends ReactiveSortingRepository<User, Long> {
     Mono<User> findByUsernameAndEmail(String username, String email);
}
```

> Find a single entity for the given criteria. It completes with IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException on non-unique results.

You can refer to the complete syntax here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/